# Calculate correlation in R (as.factor, as.numric)

Tags: r, statistics

I need to calculate a correlation between the variable 'self-confidence' (continuous) and the variable 'gender' to see if I need to include it as a possible covariate in my analysis. I have to calculate a Pearson correlation. I have used the following code for the variable 'age'.

cor1 <- cor.test(filtered_dataset$age, filtered_dataset$confidence)
print(cor1)

However, I cannot use this code for the variable 'gender' because it is classified as as.factor and not as.numeric. Can I simply change this categorization? Or is there another way to calculate this in R?

I have tried to use the above code for the variable 'gender'. Then I got the following error code:

Error in cor.test.default(filtered_dataset$Geschlecht, filtered_dataset$Glaubwuerdigkeit) :
'x' must be a numeric vector

Unfortunately, I could not find any other way to perform a Pearson correlation.

Comment: There's a discussion of how to check correlation between continuous and categorical variables over at Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484299/how-to-check-the-correlation-between-categorical-and-numeric-independent-variabl. This really isn't a programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. How exactly do you want to interpret this "correlation" value? The classic definition is for two continuous variables. This is a statistical question, not a programming one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.